# If $P(X|Y) = P(X|Y^c )$, then X and Y are independent.

Tags: probability

How do you use the law of probability to prove this?

Comment: The question is rather how **you** would use the law of probability to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You could use the law of total probability $$P(X)=P(X|Y)P(Y) + P(X|Y^c )P(Y^c)$$ and 
$$P(Y) + P(Y^c)=1$$